# Compare the head of a haskell string?

Tags: haskell

Struggling to learn Haskell, how does one take the head of a string and compare it with the next character untill it finds a character thats note true?

In pseudo code I'm trying to:

while x == 'next char in string' put in new list to be returned

Comment: +1 for requesting guidance rather than a solution

Comment: I think you're trying to find repeating characters at the beginning of a string, is this correct? Would you mind rephrasing your question?

Comment: This may not be what you're looking for, but you could benefit from understanding [`takeWhile` and `dropWhile`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:takeWhile)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The general approach would be to create a function that recursively evaluates the head of the string until it finds the false value or reaches the end.

To do that, you would need to

- understand recursion (prerequisite: understand recursion) and how to write recursive functions in Haskell
- know how to use the head function
- quite possibly know how to use list comprehension in Haskell

I have [notes on Haskell](http://www.chrisbunney.com/wiki/index.php/Category%3aHaskell) that you may find useful, but you may well find [Yet Another Haskell Tutorial](http://www.cs.utah.edu/~hal/docs/daume02yaht.pdf) more comprehensive (Sections *3.3 Lists*; *3.5 Functions*; and *7.8 More Lists* would probably be good places to start in order to address the bullet points I mention)

**EDIT0:** 
An example using guards to test the head element and continue only if it the same as the second element:

```
someFun :: String -> String 
someFun[] = [] 
someFun [x:y:xs]
    | x == y = someFun(y:xs)
    | otherwise = []
```

**EDIT1:**

> I sort of want to say x = (newlist) and then rather than otherwise = [] have otherwise = [newlist] if that makes any sense?
>   It makes sense in an imperative programming paradigm (e.g. C or Java), less so for functional approaches

Here is a concrete example to, hopefully, highlight the different between the *if,then, else* concept the quote suggests and what is happening in the `SomeFun` function:

When we call `SomeFun [a,a,b,b]` we match this to `SomeFun [x:y:xs]` and since `x` is 'a', and `y` is 'a', and `x==y`, then `SomeFun [a,a,b,b] = SomeFun [a,b,b]`, which again matches `SomeFun [x:y:xs]` but condition `x==y` is false, so we use the otherwise guard, and so we get `SomeFun [a,a,b,b] = SomeFun [a,b,b] = []`. Hence, the result of `SomeFun [a,a,b,b]` is `[]`.

So where did the data go? .Well, I'll hold my hands up and admit a bug in the code, which is now a feature I'm using to explain how Haskell functions work.

I find it helpful to think more in terms of constructing mathematical expressions rather than programming operations. So, the expression on the right of the `=` *is* your result, and *not* an assignment in the imperative (e.g. Java or C sense).

I hope the concrete example has shown that Haskell evaluates expressions using substitution, so if you don't want something in your result, then don't include it in that expression. Conversely, if you do want something in the result, then put it in the expression.

Since your psuedo code is

> while x == 'next char in string' put in new list to be returned

I'll modify the SomeFun function to do the opposite and let you figure out how it needs to be modified to work as you desire.

```
someFun2 :: String -> String 
someFun2[] = [] 
someFun2 [x:y:xs]
    | x == y = []
    | otherwise = x : someFun(y:xs)
```

Example Output:

- `SomeFun2 [a,a,b,b] = []`
- `SomeFun2 [a,b,b,a,b] = [a]`
- `SomeFun2 [a,b,a,b,b,a,b] = [a,b,a]`
- `SomeFun2 [a,b,a,b] = [a,b,a,b]`

(I'd like to add at this point, that these various code snippets aren't tested as I don't have a compiler to hand, so please point out any errors so I can fix them, thanks)

Comment: I understand recursion and how to use the head function. What I don't get and can't find any good documentation on is how to define the function in terms of syntax etc. For instance: 
someFun :: String -> String
someFun[] = []
someFun (x:xs) = 

I can't seem to get the right syntax to assign the head to a another list, then compare that with the next character. I feel a bit that if I could get my first function done it would make the rest a lot easier once I have a base to work from. Sry for the long reply!

Comment: I hope I haven't given too complete an answer, but I took the fragment in your comment and finished it off as best I could in my rusty Haskell. I think it should be a good base to start with.

Comment: Thats very helpful. I had seen someone else do it another way, but it looked a bit long winded and we've been told guarded functions are best. To use the == in a string does something else need to be declared in the type rather than just String -> String?

Comment: Never mind that last one, just me been silly. I've got it dropping the first run of characters so just some tweaking to return the dropped ones rather than whats left and I should hopefully be able to claim success at my first haskell which will be great. Thanks.

Comment: Still  abit stuck Chirs, but its becoming a little clearer. The main problem is I keep trying to think of it like other lanuages like C or Java which isn't helping.

The program snippet you wrote there, if x(the head) and y(the character after head) are equal then the function recurs. Now how do I take x and put it in a new list to return later. I sort of want to say x = (newlist) and then rather than otherwise = [] have otherwise = [newlist] if that makes any sense?

Comment: Thanks for the accepted answer, I've responded to your longish comment with an equally longish update ;) Hope it's helpful to you (and others)

Answer (score 2):

There are two typical ways to get the head of a string. `head`, and pattern matching `(x:xs)`.

In fact, [the source for the `head` function](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/src/GHC-List.html#head) shows is simply defined with pattern matching:

```
head (x:_) = x
head _     = badHead
```

I highly recommend you check out [Learn You a Haskell # Pattern Matching](http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions#pattern-matching). It gives this example, which might help:

```
tell (x:y:[]) = "The list has two elements: " ++ show x ++ " and " ++ show y
```

Notice how it pattern matched against `(x:y:[])`, meaning the list must have two elements, and no more. To match the first two elements in a longer list, just swap `[]` for a variable `(x:y:xs)`

If you choose the pattern matching approach, you will need to use recursion.

---

Another approach is the `zip xs (drop 1 xs)`. This little idiom creates tuples from adjacent pairs in your list.

```
ghci> let xs = [1,2,3,4,5]
ghci> zip xs (drop 1 xs)
[(1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(4,5)]
```

You could then write a function that looks at these tuples one by one. It would also be recursive, but it could be written as a `foldl` or `foldr`.

---

For understanding recursion in Haskell, LYAH is again highly recommended:

[Learn You a Haskell # Recursion](http://learnyouahaskell.com/recursion)

Comment: Thanks for that, I have been reading learn you a haskell, but what I don't get about that is the type. (Show a) => [a] -> String I thought the type would just be String -> String?

Comment: tell uses the show function, which converts a value of any type which implements Show into a String. Therefore the list doesn't need to be a list of characters (a String), it can be anything for which using show is valid. That's why the type signature is (Show a) => [a] -> String